# Jhipster jdl adding fake data LocalDate field is null in the database, Date format issue

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I generate an entity with

```
jhipster import-jdl hello.jdl
```

```
entity Hello {
    title String,
    myDate LocalDate
}
```

Default fake data is generated

hello.csv

```
id;title;myDate
1;mobile Fish;2019-11-17
2;Savings Account Dam;2019-11-18
```

**Problem**

However my date format is Estonian and is DD.MM.YYYY, so if I change it to following then the data is not being imported into the database. myDate field is null for both entries. Is there any way to import dates in other format than YYYY-MM-DD ?

hello.csv

```
id;title;myDate
1;mobile Fish;17.11.2019
2;Savings Account Dam;18.11.2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot change this format because Liquibase expects dates to be in "yyyy-MM-dd" format as stated in [its doc](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html):

> Date/Time values included in the CSV file should be in ISO format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 in order to be parsed correctly by Liquibase.

It's hard-coded in [liquibase.util.ISODateFormat.java](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/util/ISODateFormat.java), so there's nothing JHipster can do about it.